# Reduce Workbook File Size

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, double

I have a sparsely populated array with about 300 rows and 2500 columns of type Double. When the array is declared, all values are set initially zero. At the completion of my code which populates the array I write it to a worksheet with one statement:

```
myrange.value = myarray_dbl
```

My computation will not produce any zero values so the values that are zero when the calculation is complete could be considered blank. Is there any advantage from a code execution time and resulting file size perspective, to fill the zero valued cells with blanks before writing to a worksheet?

Comment: Seems like that's pretty easy to test?

Comment: Yes Tim I thought that after I posted. How do I replace zeros with nothing (i.e., blank) in a Double typed array? Would I loop through the double with an IF 0 skip and then write the non zero values to a variant? Or I guess I could read the Double and use the same IF 0 skip and write the values to the worksheet individually although that option might be slower.

Comment: I did a small test in Excel with this file in question. I replaced all zero values with "", and also realizing that the analysis is a prediction of a phenomenon  that cares nothing about digits to the right of decimal point (barrels of fluid per day in the hundreds of 1000's), I rounded the numbers to whole numbers. The file size went down from 7MB to 3MB. Thanks for the encouragement to figure this out on my own.